# Limit of a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm struggling with the following question:

If $A$ is a set of real numbers, let
$$g_A=\begin{cases}
1 &: x\in A \\
0 &: \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Now, consider the infinite sequence of functions $f_n$, where $f_n(x)=ng_{[0,1/n]}(x)$ for all real numbers $x$ and for each $n = 1,2,3, \dots$

Then:

(A) For every $x$, the sequence of numbers $(f_n(x))_{n=1,2,\ldots\infty}$ has a limit in the space of real numbers.

(B) $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ does not exist, for any x.

(C) when $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ exists, the actual limit depends on the $x$ in question.

(D) $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ exists for all but a finite set of real numbers $x$

**If** I've understood the question correctly, the functions $f_n$ take values $1,2,3\ldots$ over the intervals $[0,1] , [0,0.5] , [0,0.333\ldots]$,respectively, and $0$ outside of them. I think the answer should be that the limit does not exist only for $x=0$, and for all other $x$ the limit should be $1$. I would go with option (C), but I'm not sure if I've got this right. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your statement *"I think the answer should be that the limit does not exist only for $x=0$, and for all other $x$ the limit should be $1$"* is almost correct: in fact where there is a limit it is $0$ not $1$.  But anyway this is is inconsistent with C as the limit does not depend on $x$ when the limit exists.  It is consistent with D

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. Apologies for the poor formatting.

Comment: No worries. Just press the edit link below your question, or right-click on mathy stuff and select show math as -> tex-commands, and see what I've done to make it work. It's basic stuff, so it's not difficult, you just have to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist for $x=0$, correct, but for other numbers, the limit is not $1$, it is $0$.

---

Given what is written above, you know that:

- $A$ is false, because there is no limit for $x=0$
- $B$ is false, because the limit exists for $x=1$ (and any other $x\neq 0$).

Now, for $C$. You claim $C$ is correct, but when $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x)$ exists, it is **always** equal to $0$, so it does not depend on $x$ in the question. So $C$ cannot be correct.

Comment: @Arthur Either a different $x$ value or $\neq$ instead of $=$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(D) is correct. $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ exists, except when $x=0$. And the set $\{0\}$ is finite.

(C) is false. The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$, when it exists, is always equal to $0$. Therefore, it does not depend on $x$.